# NSCococErrorDomain 513 - While removing the folder from document directory - ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am trying to remove the folder from the document directory, but I am getting the NSCococErrorDomain 513. Please help me.

Simulator it works fine, but In device, it shows this error.

I have shared the code below.

Create Folder:

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Message"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
```

Delete Folder

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSMutableString *pathMString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString: [paths objectAtIndex:0]];
[pathMString appendFormat:@"/%@",@"Message"];
 NSError *err = nil;
NSString *dataPath = [NSString stringWithString:pathMString];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
{

    //DEBUGLOG(@"/n/n/n/n/n/Path/n/n/n/n/n//n/n/n/n/n//n/n/n/n/n/ : %@",dataPath);
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:dataPath error:&err];
    if (err)
    {
        //DEBUGLOG(@"Unable to delete existing file.\n" "Error: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }

}
```

thanks

Comment: Please post some code and a little more information and I would love to.  That is a no permission error, so I'm guessing you aren't working with the documents directory or that you created that folder with restricted permissions.

Comment: Why do you create the exact same string two different ways for the two different tasks?  Your create path is identical to your delete path, but you use two lines of code less to create it.

Comment: Ok I will change it .But could you please tell the why the error is coming /

Comment: If after you change it it still doesn't work, can you post a console print of the exact path you are trying to remove?